# C++ windows socket UDP packet loss

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, udp, window

I have a 10g NIC and a UDP stream of data about 3.8Gb/s. When I send packets (from another process) I lose packets on the receive side.

My CPU is at +/- 20% and the card is connected to a x8 PCIe. Jumbo packets set to 9014 Bytes (the UDP stream is very big). SO_RCVBUF set to 1073741824 (less then this number I get packet loss) and BUFLEN is 8192.

Receive function:

```
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    while (1)
    {   
        fflush(stdout);
        memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);

        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf(" recvfrom() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    ...Parsing packet...
    }
```

Set socket function:

```
    void set_sock(SOCKET *s, struct sockaddr_in *server, struct sockaddr_in *si_other)
    {
        int slen, recv_len;
        char buf[BUFLEN];
        WSADATA wsa;
        slen = sizeof(si_other);

        //Initialise winsock
        printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
        {
            printf("Failed.Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (LOBYTE(wsa.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsa.wVersion) != 2) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
            printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
            WSACleanup();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");

        //Create a socket
        if ((*s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf(" Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        printf(" Socket created.\n");

        //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
        server->sin_family = AF_INET;
        server->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server->sin_port = htons(PORT);

        int res;
        int bufferSize = 1073741824;
        int bufferSizeLen = sizeof(bufferSize);
        res = setsockopt(*s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&bufferSize, bufferSizeLen);
        if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("setsockopt for failed with error: %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        else
            printf("Set SO_RCVBUF buffer: %d\n", bufferSize);

        // If iMode != 0, non-blocking mode is enabled.
        u_long iMode = 0;
        res = ioctlsocket(*s, FIONBIO, &iMode);
        if (res != NO_ERROR)
        {
            printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %ld\n", res);
        }

        //Bind
        if (bind(*s, (struct sockaddr *)server, sizeof(*server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Bind done\n");
        }
    }
```

What else can I configure or do to prevent the packet loss when transmitting packets?

Comment: UDP is by design a unreliable protocol. It does *not* guarantee delivery and all participants in the communication *must* be ready to handle dropped / missing packages. If you want a reliable stream of data, then use TCP.

Comment: Any point along the way between your two communicating parties can drop a packet - and that's ok. You *have* to be able to deal with that. Either you ignore the missing data because you can continue without it, of you build a re-transmit mechanism into your communication (which in many cases means you are just re-implementing TCP).

Comment: ***my cpu is at +- 20%*** Is this MS Windows where that can mean an entire CPU core at full load or more or linux where 20% means 20% of a single logical CPU core

Comment: When yuo are dealing with UDP, always remember the saying, "Never mind, you probably wouldn’t get it.” That being said, there are a lot of avenues to get your packets lost, OS buffer, socket buffer, NIC, It can happen at Tx or Rx part; which you really dont have control of. So be prepared for lost packets; becasuse its just UDP. You can try writing a PDPI/PDCI NDIS driver to see whether it really came through NIC or not.

Comment: but when I use wireshark I dont have packet loss at all

Comment: @Timorleiderman Wireshark doesn't show you the whole picture.